# Selenium's webdriver is not clearing memory after quit() with Parallel webdriver sessions

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, parallel-processing, joblib

I using selenium Firefox webdriver to do some scraping like below:

```
def scrape():
    options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
    browser.get(url) # some url

    # do complex reading, element clicking and moving to and from pages

    browser.quit()
    time.sleep(5)
```

The above works well if its just one process (no parallel workers). Firefox memory consumption is stable and is cleared periodically after loading a lot of data during scraping.

However once I run the above function with `joblib` `Parallel` function. There seems to be some memory leak:

```
Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(scrape) for i in links)
```

Adding `time.sleep()` after `browser.quit()` seems to help slightly but not too much. And I notices that the smaller the no. of parallel jobs the less severe this leak is.

I have added more `time.sleep()` functions throughout the code since it might be the case that the code is to computationally intensive and `browser.quit()` is not releasing memory. But I still seem to have this problem compared to when I have just a single job.

Ultimately I want to release all firefox memory before a new job starts another `webdriver` session. This does not seem to be happening. why is that? How can this be fixed?

Comment: The question is not answered by the suggested post.